# Test to prove two means do not have a difference

Tags: mean, t-test, equivalence, group-differences

I have a population that I measure a value from once a day. I then made a change, and continued to measure that same value from the same population.

What test could I use to prove that my change did not affect the mean of that value? I'm not sure if the normal difference between two means tests that I know would apply because I want to prove that the means have no difference, not find the difference. I think this would be different from a standard t-test.

Comment: Could you elaborate on just how the before and after samples would be (statistically) *dependent*?

Comment: to summarize, you have two issues with the vanilla t-test: 1. the null hypothesis you wish to reject is that the means are different, and 2. the samples may not be independent. Is that accurate?

Comment: @whuber Well, I'm not sure if they would be or not. I guess by your leading question that its obvious that they are not.

Comment: @shabbychef Yea, those are my issues. Although I'm not sure if the independent/dependent issue is actually an issue or not.

Comment: Please don't mistake me: nothing is obvious here, because you haven't said much about the data at all.  But when data are collected sequentially in this manner, there is no manifestly apparent mechanism of dependence, so the first thing to wonder about is how dependence could arise, what its nature might be, and how strong the dependence might be.  Thus, there is a prospect that your before and after datasets might be (sufficiently) independent to justify using tests that assume independence.

Comment: @whuber Now that you put it in those terms, It seems to me that though there may be minor dependence, it should be little enough that I can assume they are independent. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking the right question?  Personally I don't think it's interesting to ask whether there is a difference.  There likely is *some* real difference, however minute, that may or may not be identified with frequentist techniques.  I personally would be more interested in estimating the likely size of the difference between the samples, and I think Bayesian techniques would help with a reframed question.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan - could you say why you'd gravitate toward a Bayesian method rather than simply compute a confidence interval and/or an effect size?

Answer (score 4):

Normally in a statistical hypothesis test, you are seeking to reject the null hypothesis in favour of the alternative hypothesis, so the precautionary principle suggests that the onus is on us to show that the null hypothesis is likely false, so we require $\alpha$, the false-positive rate (the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is true) to be low.  It is also possible to run the test the other way round, where the experimental hypothesis is the null hypothesis.  In this case the onus is on us to show that $\beta$ the false-negative rate (the probability of accepting the null hypothesis when it is false) is low.  This amounts to showing that the test has sufficient [statistical power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power).

Essentially if we are unable to reject the null hypothesis it is because the null hypothesis actually is true, or it can be because the null hypothesis is false, but we don't have enough data to be sure that it is false.  We can be confident it is the former, rather than the latter, if the test has good statistical power.

Caveat: I find frequentist statistical tests conceptually rather complicated, so I may well have written something that would make a purist wince, but hopefully the point about the need for statistical power of the t-test will be helpful.

Comment: I think you meant "if we are *un*able to reject the null hypothesis".

Comment: So to make sure that I understand you, in a t-test, the null hypothesis is that the means are the same. The power of the test is the probability that the test will reject the null hypothesis given the null hypothesis is false. So the power of the test in this case is the probability given there is a difference in means, that the test will prove a difference in means. So if the test does not prove a difference in means, is 1-(the power of the test) the probability that the means differ?

Comment: Frequentist tests don't actually allow you to assign a probability to the truth of either hypothesis, so it is quite difficult to put it into words, but essentially yes, if the null hypothesis is not rejected and the test has high statistical power, then it would be reasonable to conclude that there was no difference in the means.  However, computing the statistical power is not always straightforward, in this case I suspect it would depend on the minimum magnitude of the difference that was meaningful.  A Bayesian approach might be easier, using Bayes factors.

Comment: Thanks Dikran! So I can conclude by accepting Null hypothesis when I have good statistical power? Also it seems like there are multiple methods to do hypothesis testing such as permutation test, t-test and so on... Is one preferred over another depending on a setting?

Comment: @haneulkim yes, I gather NHSTs are sometimes conducted that way, however power calculations are often a bit tricky and just forming a null hypothesis that is the opposite of what you want to argue is more easily accepted by the reader (being more familiar).  BTW it is probably best to stick with "reject" or "do not reject" rather than "accept".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prove that there is absolutely no change unless you have infinite data/information.  However you can show that the amount of change is limited.  The best approach is probably the Bland-Altman methods, see the links on [this page](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mb55/meas/meas.htm) for more detail.  The traditional Bland-Altman method deals with 2 different measurements on the same subjects, but would work equally well for other paired data cases such as you describe.

Comment: I don't think this method would work as there isn't really a pairing between my before and after data. My data is not paired. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your description looked like you might be measuring the same units before and after, but if that is not the case, then this does not work.  You can look at equivalence testing as another approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you said that you made a change, I assume that you meant that you made a change that may impact the outcome that you are measuring.  In this case you should consider trying to measure a treatment effect, which can be recovered by difference-in-differences.

You are correct that you cannot simply compare differences in means before and after the change since unobserved variables may influence your outcome variable over time.  To control for these time effects, you would want to keep measuring one group (the control group) without the treatment and then measure a treatment group that receives the change.  If the two groups are statistically similar then we can consider the control groups outcome after the treatment period to be a proxy for the counterfactual outcome.

However, with all of this being said, you really cannot prove "no effect" but rather simply fail to reject that there is no effect.

Answer (score 1):

To show that 2 groups are eqivalent you can run an equivalence test where you compare the confidence limits against a predefined equivalence boundary. This test is similar to a t-test but the hypothesis are reversed. Instead of the null hypothesis being no difference and the alternative hypothesis being that there is a significant difference in a t test, the null hypothesis in an equivalence analysis is that the samples are not equivalent and the alternative hypothesis is that the samples are equivalent. An equivalence test thus places the burden of proof on proving equivalence. Equivalence is proved if both the lower and upper confidence bound is inside an equivalence boundary, if one of the confidence bounds is outside the equivalence limits, then equivalence cannot be concluded.
The equivalence test is available in a lot of statistical software like Minitab and SAS.